# Parsing an XML file from android using Java - First Timer

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I've been trying to figure out how to parse an XML file and save the data i get into a file.
Most of the examples i've found only consider a one depth deep list.
My XML has multiple depths and since it's my first time loading data from XML's i'm still trying to get my head around it.
This is my code but i still can't debug it so please let me know if and what i'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

```
public TestClass {
     public TestClass() {}

    public String Name;
    public String ID;
    public int Reputation;
    public List<String> ChoosenTypes;

    public TestClass(XmlPullParser inParseData) {
        int eventType = inParseData.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) { }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) { }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
             String ReadingTag = inParseData.getName();
             if (ReadingTag.equals("name")) { Name = inParseData.getText(); }
             if (ReadingTag.equals("id")) { ID = inParseData.getText(); }
             if (ReadingTag.equals("rep")) { Reputation = Integer.parseInt(inParseData.getText()); }
             if (ReadingTag.equals("types")) {
                  List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
                  if (inParseData.getDepth() == 2) {
                       while (inParseData.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                            String ReadingTagD2 = inParseData.getName();
                            if (ReadingTagD2.equals("mytypes")) {
                                 types.add(inParseData.getText());
                            }
                       }
                       ChoosenTypes = types;
                  }
             }
        }
        eventType = inParseData.next();
    }
}
```

With My XML Being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>
    <name>NAME</name>
    <id>012901</id>
    <rep>10</rep>
    <types>
        <mytypes>type 1</mytypes>
        <mytypes>type 2</mytypes>
        <mytypes>type 3</mytypes>
        <!-- The number of types is not fixed -->
    </types>
</people>
```

Please forgive me if this is completely wrong.
Just trying to Learn :D

Comment: Is your code working and do you ask for a code review? For this there exists a site for code reviews. Else please state concretely what is wrong with you program.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch the value(text) of the tag when the eventType is START_TAG.
The next eventType which will be `XmlPullParser.TEXT` shall contain the value where you can do `inParseData.getText()`. But you need to keep a track of which tag is currently being parsed.

Define the `ReadingTag` above the while statement and add the new code. That should give you a clue how you will need to retrieve all the other values.

```
 else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
   ...
   ...
 }
 // New Code 
 else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
    System.out.println(inParseData.getText());
    if (ReadingTag.equals("name")) {
      Name = inParseData.getText();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What i still don't understand is when the condition:
if (ReadingTag.equals("types")) { } results true
How do i read the understatements of "mytypes"?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to keep a track of the active tag once you get a START_TAG event. This tag could be nested several levels deep, it doesnt matter. Eventually for each tag, you will get a START_TAG, TEXT and END_TAG events. You have most of the parsing logic ready, now your code just needs to keep a track of the current tag.

Comment: Hey, Stackoverflow says i don't have the reputation yet.